# How to append class methods to a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a 'go back' feature for each sub-menu in my menu for my program, but I don't know how I can append the class methods into a list so that to 'go back', it will work in reverse order through the list (stack).

For example:

```
pages = [user_interface.page1(),user_interface.page2(),user_interface.page3()]
```

How can I append user_interface.page4() without it calling the function as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reference the functions without calling them:

```
pages = [user_interface.page1, user_interface.page2, user_interface.page3, user_interface.page4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append function reference to a list.

```
pages.append(user_interface.page4)
```

In order to call the function you need to retrieve it from the list and use as a function.

For example,

```
back = pages[-1]
back()
```